# How to install Boot Camp from content of previously created flash storage?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, bootable-disk

I've installed Windows 7 SP1 via Boot Camp before and kept the content of  the SD card that I created during the process. I want to know how I can copy that content to another SD card and install off of it again.

Probably I have to do some things manually like making the flash storage bootable and/or creating a FAT32 partition from Disk Utility.

(And no, I can't download Boot Camp due to my very limited internet connection)

My rig: OS X Yosemite (10.10.3)

Answer (score 1):

Boot Camp Assistant is already in Applications > Utilities. It doesn't need to be downloaded.

If the card was good enough to install Windows from last time, it ought to be good enough to do it again.

Comment: Probably the content of the memory card resides in a folder somewhere on the Mac as single files and (sub-)folders and the memory card was rededicated since.

Comment: The bootcamp utility in Applications folder doesn't state anything about any cached install files, it shows regular options when I launch it.

@klanomath: That would be good but where?

Comment: @idn Where to you keep the "content of the SD" you created duing the first Win7 install? Is it still on the SD or somewhere else?

Comment: @klanomath it's on my HDD.

Content are stored on my hard drive, there is nothing on any SD card or USB.

I've tried making my SD card bootable with "Rufus" and then copying content into it but it didn't show up as bootable in OS X's boot menu (holding Option as the system boots up).